# Parsing text in a file with regex

Tags: python, regex, file

I'm trying to parse a `.txt` file with regex:

```
#file = '22 test 333'

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    pattern = '\d\d(?=\s)'    # should match 22
    data = re.compile(pattern)
    print f.read()            # prints '22 test 333'
    print data.findall(f.read())   # outputs an empty list []
```

Regex is correct. Why after I read the file, regex no longer matches? And finally how to parse text from a file using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read the file *already*. The file pointer is now at the end and you won't read any more data.

Store the file data once:

```
contents = f.read()
print contents                 # prints '22 test 333'
print data.findall(contents)   # outputs ['22']
```

Alternatively, seek back to the start:

```
print f.read()                 # prints '22 test 333'
f.seek(0)
print data.findall(f.read())   # outputs ['22']
```

or reopen the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file which is already read. If you omit the "print f.read()" line, everything should work. Alternatively, after printing file, you can do "f.seek(0)", and that should return the cursor in file to the first position.

Answer (score 1):

Store the return value from `f.read()` into a variable. The first `f.read()` actually reads the whole data and places the file pointer at the end of the file. So, next `file.read()` actually returns an empty string `''`.

```
text = f.read()
print data.findall(text)
```